# What is hello program?

Tags: 14.04, apt, debian, installed-programs

I typed in `hello` on a server I logged in after a long time, as a humorous greeting. I got this:

```
ubuntu@server:~$ hello
The program 'hello' can be found in the following packages:
 * hello
 * hello-debhelper
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

So what are `hello` and `hello-debhelper` programs? What are they used for?

This seems impossible to Google, btw.

Comment: You can install it and run `man hello`.

Comment: sorry??? http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/hello.1.html If I can find it in less than a minute... so can you :+) and `info help` @pilot6 shows the manual :)

Comment: @Pilot6 Good suggestion, but I wanted to know what it is first, before installing anything. But it seems like [nothing to worry about](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hello). (Found that by Googling `linux man hello`, which I didn't think of before.)

Comment: To add another command to get information about that package: `apt-cache show hello`

Comment: @Thomas great suggestion! Make it an answer.

Comment: What's with the downvote? Is there a genuine reason or _you just hatin' bro?_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to test if the Software application in Ubuntu is working properly, you can install a little application called *hello* and give it a try from the terminal.

The hello program from the default Ubuntu repositories outputs `Hello, world!`

```
~$ hello
Hello, world!
```

*hello-debhelper* is an example of how to do a Debian package. hello-debhelper is the same as the hello package, except it uses debhelper to make the deb. *debhelper* is a collection of programs that can be used in a debian/rules file to automate common tasks related to building Debian packages (Ubuntu uses the same packaging system as Debian).

Comment: I think it would be useful to mention that what deb packages are , just to make it clear for the newbies

Answer (score 9):

One possible solution could be as follows:

```
apt-cache show hello
apt-cache show hello-debhelper
```